# Postman script to JMeter script

Tags: jmeter, postman, jmeter-plugins

We have several Postman HTTP scripts,

We would like to convert it to JMeter scripts, is there a simple conversion tool/option? should we use recording as suggested in [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-Postman-with-JMeter) ?

> 1. Launch Postman and setup the proxy server under File>Settings>Proxy to use port as localhost:8087.
> 2. Launch JMeter tool, open recording template and setup the proxy to use the port '8087' under 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' element (same port that is set in Postman)
> 3. Now all the API requests that you send in Postman will be captured in JMeter and store under Thread Group>Recording Controller.

Comment: please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQWyLMJbXaw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggestion seems to be one of the quickest ways of doing this - Using the Collection Runner would help speed up the capture process.

Here's a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/xKWPu7-aqE4) I found going through this solution.

Answer (score 5):

[Loadium](https://loadium.com/) have an new Postman to JMeter converter:

You can use our new feature by [uploading Postman's JSON file](https://loadium.com/postman-to-jmeter-converter/) and click CONVERT NOW

Comment: Its very useful. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. Every json file I upload (for v2 or v2.1 collection), it just says an error occurred.

Comment: After signing up and going through some things. v2 did work for me. But the link to it is different.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is good if not the best.

However if your Postman scripts assume any form of **correlation** you will need to manually handle dynamic data using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), you can consider an alternative way of recording your tests using cloud proxy server which is capable of exporting recorded requests in SmartJMX mode with automatic correlation applied. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more details.

Comment: The link to "How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%" is not working any more.

Comment: Try this one: [Recording Your Session](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354686189457-Recording-Your-Session), look for `SmartJMX` option

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-postman-jmeter

Latest changes seem to make v2.1 work (at least in some cases)

I was using testcafe hook and https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-collection to build collections before using above to convert to jmeter. And https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-to-openapi to convert it to OpenAPI.

A postman ItemGroup describing each e2e test file. And adding items for each request in order.