# Postman integration with JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter, postman

I'd like to point out that this current question is a follow-up to an earlier post that talks about using Postman in conjunction with JMeter. That other thread can be found here:
[Postman script to JMeter script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009587/postman-script-to-jmeter-script)

Anyways, the original thread suggested that JMeter could record the traffic that a Postman collection would trigger by following the below procedures:

> 1- Launch Postman and setup the proxy server under File>Settings>Proxy to
>   use port as localhost:8087.
>
> 2- Launch JMeter tool, open recording template and setup the proxy to use
>   the port '8087' under 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' element (same
>   port that is set in Postman)
>
> 3- Now all the API requests that you send in Postman will be captured in
>   JMeter and store under Thread Group>Recording Controller.

I've tried to setup the proxy in Postman but that doesn't work for me (unless I'm missing something).

When I run a collection with no proxy defined, I get the responses just fine. But when I flip the "custom proxy" on (using localhost:8087), I get this error:

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8087

I've gone through some solutions posted on GitHub but with no success. If its any relevant, I'm on Windows 7. Anyone familiar with this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting means that Postman is not capable of connecting to JMeter, so please double check that:

- HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is really configured to use port 8087
- HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is started

If you would like to start from scratch:

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature). From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click `Create`

   [image]
2. Change Port to `8087` and click "Start"

   [image]
3. If you still experience any problems - look into [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging).
4. It might also be the case you will need to [install JMeter's self-signed certificate into Postman](https://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/)

Comment: You sir, have just made my day!

For the record, I had to tweak the solution a bit. Since im using postman (not browser extension), the certificate didn't apply. BUT, in the Settings --> General, I disabled the SSLCertification Verification and with the other steps, it now works...

Mr. Dmitri, I had a tough day yesterday and this one is looking much brighter thanks to you!!