# JMeter script to Postman conversion

Tags: json, jmeter, postman

I have searched on internet, there are lot of ways to convert Postman script to JMeter script, but none showing vice versa.

Have a JMeter API script and want to convert to Postman Collection or Postman readable format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009587/postman-script-to-jmeter-script

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user7294900, but I need to convert JMeter script to Postman and not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman has a proxy built-in:

- https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests/

Start it, then configure in JMeter the proxy to point to Postman:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Run plan and you're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work as expected. Saved a lot of time.

Comment: @SAIR  can you help me in this issue

Comment: @sufyankhalid what is the issue?

Comment: @SAIR I have a script on jMeter that I used previously while working for load testing, but now I want to switch my jMeter jMX script to Postman. So, since I'm having the same problem as you, could you please assist me?

Comment: @sufyankhalid just follow the answer, nothing else. It will work

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction to UBIK LOAD PACK answer, what worked for me on windows:

1 Enable proxy listening mode on Postman
[image]

2 Restart postman

3 Run the script via CLI, to generate some data as:

```
jmeter -n -t SimpleController.jmx -l log.jtl -H 127.0.0.1 -P 9999
```

(assuming your script name is: SimpleController.jmx)

4 You should be able to see the data in Postman history
[image]

Comment: I tried everything, and it all works fine, except the capture doesn't stop after the test run. For example, in my test plan, I have 100 requests, and these requests run continuously without stopping.

Comment: of course, won't stop after the run. your proxy Listener is still active. disable step 1. and won't record any more