# POSTMAN-TOKEN JMeter equivalent?

Tags: http, jmeter, postman

I trying to craete HTTP request test for my server in JMeter.

sorry about the links for screenshots, I can't add a picture yet...

the next HTTP requests (of course before the logout) don't work (with the errors):

- create filter

> Response code:400
> Response message:Bad Request

- get all filters

> Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException
> Response message:Non HTTP response message: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 53,145; received: 49,218)

> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 53,145; received: 49,218)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
> at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
> at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1936)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:476)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:673)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
> at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**these two HTTP requests work for me in postMan**

[createFilter postman screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dz-Tzg3b-cGn7R83-cb_MsKj27y6WQtv/view?usp=sharing)
(there is body too, but probably it's not the problem, I did copy-paste)

[getAllFilters postman screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fH9w6klnH3mtTu7skn8KLe5-XpEg3vG7/view?usp=sharing)

**edit:**

As you can see in them both I have "POSTMAN-TOKEN" in the HTTP headers.

thanks to @Dmitri T I compared the requests from POSTMAN and after I add the "POSTMAN-TOKEN" with his value to JMeter all worked (read about it in this link: [what-is-the-postman-token-header-attribute-in-generated-code-from-postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883046/what-is-the-postman-token-header-attribute-in-generated-code-from-postman)).

the POSTMAN-TOKEN calculated when request is sent. what is the JMeter equiualent?

Thanks!

thanks to @Dmitri T! work like a magic
after this I saw it was answered here already:
[postman-script-to-jmeter-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009587/postman-script-to-jmeter-script)

and one more online service (didn't checked):
[online-postman-to-jmeter-converter](https://loadium.com/postman-to-jmeter-converter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend Google Drive permissions as the screenshots are not accessible.

In the meantime I can give you one generic hint: if the requests are "working" in Postman they will also "work" in JMeter given JMeter sends the same requests as Postman does.

- Either cross check request and pay attention to literally everything, URL, request body, [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header), etc. and it's better to use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) as both tools don't show everything
- or just record the requests from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) like:

  1. Start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
  2. [Import JMeter's self-signed certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/) if you're using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol
  3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
  4. Run your request(s) in Postman
  5. JMeter will capture the requests and create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, [HTTP Header Managers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), etc.

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Comment: fixed the links. thanks for your suggest, will try.